# How do I set up Nginx rewrite rules in a config file generated from PuPHPet?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puphpet

Example from "config.yaml" file:

```
locations:
  ...
  some_location_root:
    location: /
    try_files:
      - $uri
      - '@rwr'

  some_location_rewrite:
    location: '@rwr'
    rewrite: '^(.*) /index.php?_controller=$1 last'
  ...
```

Comment: I think you better read next portion of docs. I see no trouble here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/spec/defines/resource_location_spec.rb

```
rewrite: '^(.*) /index.php?_controller=$1 last'
```

Should look like:

```
rewrite_rules: ['^(.*) /index.php?_controller=$1 last']
```

Comment: How to handle multiple rules? I tried rewrite_rules: ['first', 'second'] but it does not work for me :/ Any ideas?